# My external style sheet has the exact same code as the html file for an object but it doesn't style as much as the embedded style?

Tags: html, css

Okay, so this makes no sense; a little while ago I was playing around with the `<h1>` tag and I added it to my style sheet. Then I found out I already have that tag below in the style sheet, but when I deleted the old style the colour of the heading goes back to black despite copying and pasting the exact same thing in the two locations.

Furthermore, code to style an object shows up differently in the style sheet and the embedded style, as when I delete the embedded style the object loses its border despite having the same border in the stylesheet. How can I fix this? I want to transfer all of my styles onto the style sheet.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Styles cascade. Part of what that means is that if two styles have the same exact specificity, the one that comes second will take precedence. When you move styles from a `<style>` tag to a `.css` file, you may also be moving where it loads in the HTML dom to be before or after some other conflicting CSS. You'll want to either load the `.css` file at the same place as where the `<style>` tag or more ideally adjust the specificity so that load order isn't the only factor deciding which rules to use.